# Compiling SDL on OS X with Haskell fails

Tags: macos, haskell, sdl

I can't get my SDL program to even *build* on OS X; I get this error:

```
/Users/<redacted>/code/<redacted>/.hsenv/cabal/lib/SDL-0.6.4/ghc-7.4.1/HSSDL-0.6.4.o: unknown symbol `_SDL_HasSSE2'
```

I've tried recompiling SDL from source, installing it from macports; nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the problem is, but when I was on OSX I had lots of problems with 7.4.1. After upgrading to 7.4.2 through HomeBrew most of the issues were gone. So I suggest trying 7.4.2. Hope you get your issue fixed.